# What can I use on .NET CF as a replacement for HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I need to move .NET code to the Compact Framework. That code uses HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode query parameters, but System.Web isn't available on CF. What can I use instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).  It's nearly equivalent, and probably better anyway, and is included in NetCF.

[More info on their differences](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/05/uriescapedatapath-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at bundling [mono's implementation](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpUtility.cs?revision=131599&view=markup) (optionally simplified).  I don't know how many of the dependencies you'd have to bring in, though.  It may or may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to roll your own, or even better, cheat. Using reflector you will quickly see that there are a number of overloaded methods for UrlEncode, calling the version that just expects the string paramater eventually ends up converting the string to an array of bytes and calling an internal method.

Edit: Code snippet removed in case of copyright violation...

Comment: Tim, including decompiled copywrited software on the web seems like a license violation to me.

Comment: Andrew, well...MS did release the FCL source with VS2008. However, even so, you are probably correct. Just releasing it with a commercial product does not automatically give me rights to post it I guess. I'll edit the answer just in case. (a brain fart to post it in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

I used `Uri.EscapeUriString` instead since `Uri.EscapeDataString` encodes the full string, not just the parameters, for example

```
http://website.com/a/abc{d}d
```

With EscapeDataString it gets transformed to:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Fa%2Fabc%7Bd%7Dd
```

And with Uri.EscapeUriString, it correctly turns into this:

http://website.com/a/abc%7Bd%7Dd